# How can I install pywinauto recorder using .exe file

Tags: python

How can I install pywinauto recorder using .exe file but not from command prompt using pip install pywinauto because after installing from command prompt I am not able to open recorder.

Installed from command prompt and not able to open the recorder.

Or from where can I download pywinautorecorder.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the installer on the main page of the documentation:

https://pywinauto-recorder.readthedocs.io/

Click on the first big green button ("Click here to DOWNLOAD")